# Cycles removes assigned material from mesh faces altered by a displacement map, instead leaving them plain white

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

Let me preface this with the statement that I'm a complete Blender beginner. Literally started modelling yesterday.

Here's the deal. I'm modelling a very simple tyre, and testing out different displacement map patterns, in order to be able to generate a nice complex tread in PS where I feel more confident, instead of having to model it directly in Blender. Here you can see said tyre in object mode with the map applied:

[image: tyre model as seen in object mode]

Whenever I render the image however, some weird artefacts show through on the tyre wall and more importantly, the tread grooves don't show the texture I have assigned to the mesh. It looks like this:

[image: tyre model as seen after render]

There is no doubt in my mind that this has some absurdly straightforward solution, but I simply have no idea what that might be. The only avenue of logic I can go down is that for some reason, at rendering time, the displacement map separates the mesh faces that it alters from the rest of the object, thus breaking the link between them and the assigned material. But what confuses me is why it doesn't do the same thing when I'm in edit/object mode.

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your file here (with textures packed in it) http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? That will help to understand/find the problem

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2714/ Didn't have the rep to put it in the main post, so here it is. .blend with textures packed in

Comment: Also don't mind the naming convention. All my files have obscenities in their names.

Comment: This is due to the object "tyre2". It is not visible in the viewport (as hidden in the outliner) but rendered.

Comment: What did I say about an absurdly straightforward solution. :D Could you please add this comment as an answer so I can mark it. And thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this was not a Cycles problem.

Simply there is another tyre named "tyre2" in the scene which is hidden for the viewport but rendered :

[image]

To avoid it to be rendered, click also on the little camera icon on the right.